# Using angularjs uib-typeahead to show viewvalue different from ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a uib-typeahead input.

I need to use a async call to populate it.
I´d like to set ng-model to "CODIGO", but I need the viewvalue showing 
"DESCRICAO".
My problem is that after I select a item, ng-model is correct but the viewvalue is not the "DESCRICAO". It is the "CODIGO" as well.

getCBOEspecialidadesByDesc is a async service returning:

```
[{CODIGO:1, DESCRICAO:'TESTE1'},
{CODIGO:2, DESCRICAO:'TESTE2'},
{CODIGO:3, DESCRICAO:'TESTE3'}
....
]
```

//controller

```
$scope.getAllProfissoes=function(val){
    return dataService.getCBOEspecialidadesByDesc(val).then((response)=> {
         return response.data.results
      }, (erro)=> {
        console.log(erro)
      }
  )}
```

//markup

```
    <input name="usuarioProfissional.prof" type="text" ng-model="profissional.COD_CBO_3" 
    uib-typeahead="item.CODIGO as item.DESCRICAO for item in getAllProfissoes($viewValue)" 
    typeahead-editable="false" 
    class="form-control">
```

Mysql tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE STAFF (
    ID                       BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL
    , ATIVO                  BOOLEAN   NOT NULL
    , NOME                   VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
    , COD_CBO_3              VARCHAR( 10 )
    , CONSTRAINT PK_STAFF_NH
        PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
    )ENGINE=INNODB;


   //used to fill COD_CBO_3  in staff table 
   CREATE TABLE CBO_ESPECIALIDADES (
    ID                          BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL
    , CODIGO                    VARCHAR( 10 )
    , DESCRICAO                 VARCHAR( 255 )
    , CONSTRAINT PK_ESPEC_NH
        PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
    )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

//angular service

```
angular.module("clinang").service('dataService', ['$http','config', function ($http,config) {

   var urlBase = config.baseUrl;

    this.getCBOEspecialidadesByDesc = function (sel) {
                return $http.get(urlBase+'/cbo_especialidades/ByDesc/'+sel);
            };
}]);
```

//server router

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const callback=function(err,data,res){
     console.log(data)
     if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
     return res.status(200).send(data);
}
//used by getCBOEspecialidadesByDesc angular service
router.get('/ByDesc/:id',function(req,res,next){    
    const searchString=req.params.id||'';
    var params = ['%'+searchString+'%'];
    console.log(params);
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            var ret
            connection.query('select * from CBO_ESPECIALIDADES where descricao like ?',params, function (error, results, fields) {
              if (error){
                 ret={success:false, results:error}
              }
              else {
               ret={success:true, results:results}
              }
              callback(error,ret,res)
            });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way uib-typeahead works.

You can use two tricks to perform what you want.

### 1) Save the entire object as model

// markup

```
<input name="usuarioProfissional.prof" type="text" ng-model="profissional.COD_CBO_3" 
    uib-typeahead="item as item.DESCRICAO for item in getAllProfissoes($viewValue)" 
    typeahead-editable="false" 
    class="form-control">
```

`profissional.COD_CBO_3` will contains the whole object. `{CODIGO:1, DESCRICAO:'TESTE1'}` you have to take it into account when manipulating it.

### 2) Keep the CODIGO - DESCRICAO mapping and use a formatter

// JS

```
$scope.formatter = function(model) {
  return $scope.mappings.get(model);
}
$scope.mappings = new Map();
$scope.getAllProfissoes=function(val){
  return dataService.getCBOEspecialidadesByDesc(val).then((response)=> {
       response.data.results.forEach((result) => {$scope.mappings.set(result.CODIGO, result.DESCRICAO);})
       return response.data.results
    }, (erro)=> {
      console.log(erro)
    }
)}
```

// Markup

```
<input name="usuarioProfissional.prof" type="text" ng-model="profissional.COD_CBO_3" typeahead-input-formatter="formatter($model)"
    uib-typeahead="item.CODIGO as item.DESCRICAO for item in getAllProfissoes($viewValue)" 
    typeahead-editable="false" 
    class="form-control">
```

You can view [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SPXfetyB47VZvm4cXyqw?p=preview) an example with this solution (Asynchronous results part).

### Wich solution to use

The solution depends of your use case. If you need to repopulate the field somewhere (edit form by example) you should consider the first one.

If you don't need to repopulate it you can use the second one.

Comment: Thank  you for your excellent response. If I use the first option, the CODIGO is saved into server correctly. But, when I get this item from server the typeahead shows the "CODIGO", not the DESCRICAO. How could I handle it?

Comment: Only as information, I use nodejs+mysql as backend.

Comment: Do you know other package to handle this case directly without workarounds?

Comment: If my data was a static array, I could  to use a map. But they are asyncronous

Comment: Hey Luiz, for your problem, can you add in the OP how you are getting back the data from your server ? Honestly, I tried several packages 1-2 years ago for typeahead and it was the best. As angular 1.X is dying, you should avoid other packages that won't be maintened.

Comment: Thank you I put the code used in the  server and more code used on front end.

Comment: Seeing tout code, I reconsider my answer concerning an other lib. You should consider [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)